# Mailkit does not authenticate with credentials

Tags: email, smtp, smtpclient, mailkit, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send an email with Gmail account. I was able to send emails with yahoo, however, it doesn't work anymore, for some unknown reason. Which i posted a question about that as well, but not response.

In this instance, i'm trying to connect to a gmail account so that I can send emails, but with no luck, it fails after the Connect.

It connects successfully but doesn't authenticate at all, although I have the right credentials.

This is the error i'm getting. I want to mention that the credentials are right.

```
{"535: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  
  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l17sm22879081wro.77 - gsmtp"}
```

Should I use any certificates or something? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the code.

The code

```
var message = new MimeMessage();

        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(contactModel.Name, "s@gmail.com"));
        // This needs to be put in a configuration file
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("test", "a@gmail.com"));

        message.Subject = $"{contactModel.Name} contacted me!";
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") {
            Text = contactModel.Message + 
            " Details of sender: " + contactModel.EmailAddress + ", " + contactModel.ContactNumber + " ," + contactModel.Name
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!client.IsConnected)
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587,false);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                }
                if (!client.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync("s@gmail.com", "password");
                }

                await client.SendAsync(message);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);

                return "success";
            }
            catch (SmtpCommandException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (SmtpProtocolException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"The email from {contactModel.EmailAddress} captured but not sent to the owner");
            }

        }
```

[image]

And I got this email in my inbox, how I can bypass this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do is to sign-in to your Google Mail account in a web browser, go to Settings, and then check "Enable less secure apps". I believe this url will get you there if you are already signed in: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I'm having the same problem over here and already allowed less secure apps but to no use. Besides that, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE (copied from Gmail docs): "To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password."

Answer (score 9):

First:

- enable two factor authentication for your Gmail account by going to [Google Support: Protect your account with 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and enabling it.

Then:

- generate a 16-symbols password by going to [Gmail Security Settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)
- use the generated code instead of your password for authentication.

Comment: This is the most correct answer I've found.

Comment: The accepted answer should be changed to this answer as Gmail stopped supporting the `less secure apps` option.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still having this issue can follow this beautiful link with picturesque instructions:

```
https://help.warmupinbox.com/en/articles/4934806-configure-for-google-workplace-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa
```

So you basically need to enable iMAP from Settings (click Gears and not Security Tab)

Then Goto Security Tab -> App Password -> Other(custom name), give it any name and use the generated password.

I haven't tried without disabling two factor authentication though my hunch is it should work without enabling 2FA